# .NET: Possible to upload multiple files to MULTIPLE target folders?

Tags: .net, file-upload

I realize that the file upload control in .NET 4.5 can upload multiple files at once to a single folder but is it possible to upload to parse them into separate folders?  For example, if the hundreds of files are named with different names, can they be automatically uploaded to same named folders.  I realize that I will need the folders to be created on the fly as well.

If this is possible how could I do it?
Thanks in advance.  I did try searching for quite some time but I haven't found anything close yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that should work. Your upload control has a PostedFiles property that contains an `IList<HttpPostedFile>`. An HttpPostedFile object has it's own SaveAs method, see here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx

So, you could just do something like (counter just for illustration):

```
int i = 0;
foreach(HttpPostedFile file in Upload1.PostedFiles)
{
  i++;
  file.SaveAs("C:\\Temp\\" + i + "\\" + file.Filename);
}
```

Comment: Thanks ThomasC!.  So if I want the target folders to be named after the substring part of the filename that contains the person's name, can I replace the "i" in the SaveAs with the substring in the "Filename"?

Comment: Yeah, sure. It was just an example showing that the path can be different for each file. You basically construct the path however you want, using information from the file name, or whatever works for you. I'm not sure if the SaveAs method creates that folder for you, though, so you might need to check if it exists first, and then create it if it doesn't (make sure your code has enough file system permissions for that)

Comment: Thanks again.  I don't have enough reputation points to up vote your answer.